# Object properties not getting set in C#

Tags: c#, linq

This is a strange problem I'm having, I have the following statement:

```
IEnumerable<CategoryListViewModel> categoryViewModels = categoryRepository.GetAllCategoryViewModels();
```

This correctly populates with exactly one element.

```
categoryViewModels.Where(cvm => cvm.CategoryId == localId).Single().Selected = true;
```

Yet, nothing gets updated, selected remains false. I can verify that the CategoryId and the localId are equal, if I break out:

```
var something = categoryViewModels.Where(cvm => cvm.CategoryId == localId).Single()
```

It correctly returns the one viewModel.  In fact, if I go in and I set the local variable "something" to Selected = false. It'll correctly update the local variable.

Am I missing something obvious?

Edit:

```
public class CategoryListViewModel
{
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can we see definition of CategoryViewModel?

Comment: Sorry, but your code above mentions CategoryViewModel, but your example says CategoryListViewModel...  typo?

Comment: If CategoryViewModel is a value type, this could be an issue...

Comment: @Tigran: actually if it's a value type it won't compile...  I already played with that to see :-)

Comment: at this point, may he just confused collections? :) Hard and late evening at office, it happens...

Comment: I like Stuart's thought that perhaps the source is a database, so he's modifying something in memory but not the root data source.  We need the question author @chum of chance to clarify though if this is the case or not (database vs collection).

Comment: Fixed CategoryListViewModel typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem might be that `categoryViewModels` is actually an `IQueryable` - so when you enumerate it, then it makes a database call and SELECTs a list from the database.

This means you create a list, and then change `selected` for one item in that list.

However... next time you enumerate `categoryViewModels` then this causes another SELECT to occur - and a new list to be fetched into memory.

To fix this, you could try `ToList()`:

```
IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel> categoryViewModels = categoryRepository.GetAllCategoryViewModels().ToList();
```

or you could reorganise your code in some other way to ensure only one underlying query is performed.

Comment: That is an interesting point!  I was taking the IEnumerable at face value.

Comment: I think this is the problem... I read the question and was about to post a "are you sure?" message - then I noticed the `categoryRepository` name :)

Answer (score 0):

This is odd, I have the following bit of code and it works for me:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    List<CategoryListViewModel> list = new List<CategoryListViewModel>
                                        {
                                            new CategoryListViewModel
                                                { CategoryId = guid, CategoryName = "Hi", Selected = false }
                                        };

    list.Where(cvm => cvm.CategoryId == guid).Single().Selected = true;

    Console.WriteLine(list[0].Selected);
}

public class CategoryListViewModel
{
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

I can't recreate your issue, it shows true for me once I perform the LINQ.  Can you post your whole code, maybe there's a side-effect we don't see in the snippet...